# Laravel route returning error 404 when attempt is made to pass value to controller function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have a button in my blade like this

```
@can('customer_show')
                <a class = "btn btn-primary" href = "{{ route('admin.loan-applications.showCustView', $loanApplication->user_id) }}">
                    View Applicant 
                </a>
            @endcan
```

And this is the route:

```
Route::get('loan-applications/{loan_application}/showCustView', 'loanApplicationsController@showCust')->name('loan-applications.showCustView');
```

And in my controller, i did:

```
public function showCust(LoanApplication $loanApplication)
{
    
    
    $customerInformation = customerInfoModel::where('Cust_id', $loanApplication->user_id));
     
    return view('admin.loanApplictions.showCustView', compact(['customerInformation', 'loanApplication']));
}
```

What i am trying to do is fetch the row from the database attached to customerInfoModel where the the Cust_id field equals the loanApplication->user_id of the loan being viewed currently in the blade above. When the button "view Applicant" is hit, i get an error 404 page. Why is that so?

Comment: you're adding an admin prefix to the blade, do you have that in the route file?

Comment: @omar, yes. I have run PvP artisan route:list. That is how it appears.

Comment: @Zeekstem Your definition for route is named as ```loan-applications.showCustView``` but you used ```admin.loan-applications.showCustView``` in your blade file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it out the route list using this command

`php artisan route:list`

//this command will show all the routes in your application

If your route not listed on that route list checkout for routes with same Url on your route manually on routes file.

if you found change the url & use this command to clear cache

`php artisan optimize:clear`

i have found the comment of you on last answer.
check out for route model binding . i think you have to add
a

```
public function showCust( $loanApplicationCustId)
{
    
    $customerInformation = customerInfoModel::where('Cust_id', $loanApplicationCustId))->first();
     
    return view('admin.loanApplictions.showCustView', compact(['customerInformation', 'loanApplication']));
}
```

It should be like this .. i hope it works for you......
else share your project git repo link

Comment: It works! Thanks very much for showing me the right way to do route model binding. By the way, I had to add to this line like this `$CustomerInformation = CustomerInfoModel::where('Chat_I'd',    $loanApplicationCustId))->first():`

Comment: Sry for that I have not noticed that.... Query i have focused on 404 not found error.....that why i have not mentioned let i change the solution...  Have a great day

Comment: After so much trouble, php artisan optimize:clear saved my day

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like following:

```
@can('customer_show')
                <a class = "btn btn-primary" href = "{{ route('loan-applications.showCustView', $loanApplication->user_id) }}">
                    View Applicant 
                </a>
            @endcan
```

try that

Comment: I get error Route not defined. PHP artisan route:list shows the route with admin prefix

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered a similar issue with route model binding where I was unable to access a specific route even though it was properly defined. After extensive debugging, I discovered that the problem was caused by missing headers. It is important to include the following headers in your request to prevent a 404 error:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Including these headers ensures that the request is treated as a JSON request and that the server knows how to handle and interpret the data correctly.